# pyinstaller for gui that runs other python scripts

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I created a GUI in python which runs some other python scripts (4 separate files). When I used pyinstaller for the gui to convert it to an executable, it could not run the other python scripts. I read somewhere that I must include them in the spec file but i am not sure how. Any help?

Comment: Can you paste your code and error information?

Comment: master = Tk()
master.title("runcode")
master.geometry("640x640")

def openfile1():
    os.startfile("file1.py")
Button1 = Button(Labelframe2)
Button1.place(relx=0.48, rely=0.85, height=24, width=47)
Button1.configure(text='''Button One''')
Button1.configure(command=openfile1)

master.mainloop()